# Django - Limit object level access based on foreign key

Tags: django

I have a django data model that roughly looks like

```
class Project:
     ...
     owner = FK(User)
class User:
     ...
     project = FK(Project)
class Data: 
     ....
     project = FK(Project)
```

And I'd like to enforce that a User can only interact (view/delete whatever) with Data if his he has a FK to the Project that the Data does.

I can query this at every access point but I think that's error prone, and am also concerned about performance penalty of frequent joins. Are their other alternatives ?
Thanks

Comment: Where would you like to limit a user's rights to edit specific models?
I mean, on some kind of a template? Admin page? Where?

Comment: Everywhere. 
So user accesses the data via an API with DRF, mostly through custom views as opposed to viewsets.

Answer (score 1):

So I realized what I want is multi tenancy which doesn't come out of the box in Django. 
Their are some packages that do schema level isolation but I think I will go with full database isoltation.

Comment: Exactly. If you need a global model level access control, there is no better solution than constraints in the db layer.